# Creating an Android Lint Checks that forces users to make javadocs. (Explain like you are explaining it to a new developer)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create an android lint checks for android 3.5; It needs to satisfy 2 things:

1.) Must compile an error if the brace does not start in the next line. 
2.) Must compile an error if there is no javadoc on each method.

Any help on how to implement these checks would be greatly appreciated. I looked at other resources, including the android documentation and do not know how to set up the implementation so everything can work out.

I have looked at the android documentation. While it doesn't look hard, I do not know where to begin to configure the project for the custom lint checks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article how to do it https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-lint

In the nutshell: 
1. Add `'com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.1.2'` and `'com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.2'` as a dependency.
2. Create your custom rule.
3. Create a detector, which will detect the issue.
4. Wired detector to issue.
5. Add the issue to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're set on using Lint for this.
I achieved the same thing with checkstyle. 
here's a [demo project](https://github.com/smarkovik/make-or-break/) where I demonstrate how to do all of that.

The specific config is made [here](https://github.com/smarkovik/make-or-break/blob/master/config/codestyle/codestyle.xml#L330)

And the blogpost about it you can [read here](https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/make-or-break-with-gradle-dac2e858868d)

Hope this helps. Look around, the blogpost and the project have a ton of other stuff you might wanna re-use.